# Time zone difference between client and server

Tags: c#, reactjs, datetime, .net-core

I am having the common problem of client vs server time differences. I have a date range filter where the user selects the start and end date of data in a report. The web app is done using React.

When the user sends the request, I use moment.js to set the start date as the start of the selected date, and the end date as the end of the selected ending date. If I run this locally and inspect the values I get 12:00:00 AM as the start *time* and 12:59:59 PM as the end *time*. I send that to the back end, a .net core application. Locally that works fine, but once in staging, all the records that have the exact start date are excluded. However, if I truncate the start date in the server I do retrieve those records.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowByDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        startDate = startDate.Date; //<-- this 'fixes' my problem
        var shabbatonInfo = _context.ProgramSessions
            .Where(ps => ps.StartDate >= startDate && ps.StartDate <= endDate);
        return await GetData(shabbatonInfo);
    }
```

The problem is, since the time is converted from 12:00:00 AM to, say, 04:00:00 AM, then the end date is probably being moved as well, to the next day (I don't have records in the database to test this, nor I can mangle with it). I have looked around and mostly all answers say to store the data in GMT, but this doesn't seem to be my problem or if it is, I sure cannot change the database as it's a legacy one.

Comment: I don't see how the time can be changed 12.00-> 12.04. If you send 12.00.000 from the client you should have the same 12.00.00 on the  the server. Sure you may have difference in timezone. But to handle you either should  have server in UTC (GMT) and convert client time to UTC or make sure that you operate in one timezone, if your clients only use app in one timezone.

Comment: @MikhailChibel I tried to say 12:00:00 to 04:00:00. Sorry about that.

Comment: unfortunately my answer will be as well, store data in GMT :). If you cannot change timezone in DB, then you just need to convert client time into server one. Question is if user selects 12 am what records do you want to extract from the DB for the 12 am of the same day? What if you have 2 clients in different timezones and they both ask for data on 12 AM should they receive same data?

Comment: Related: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx